# Implementing Identity Server 3 as Auth. Provider for Salesforce

Tags: authentication, login

Has anybody tried implementing an [Identity Server 3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) as an Auth. Provider in Salesforce?

We're trying to use Windows Authentication without using ADFS in the Single Sign-On Settings in Salesforce. It's because we want to create a custom login page, rather than ADFS's static login page.

Comment: Auth Provider uses OpenId Connect to authenticate with your Identity provider application, and Identity Server 3 supports that. However to use the Windows authentication, you might need to explore JWT tokens. I couldn't understand much about your issue with "Custom login page", what's the issue there?

Comment: I see, let me check on JWT tokens for Identity Server 3 then. Ah custom login page because currently we have an ADFS implementation as another means of authentication in SFDC and it has its own static login page that is shared by several other relying parties thus offering very minimal customization.